# Scaling SVG text in upper left corner of image

Tags: svg, text, css-transforms

I'm trying to dynamically add text to the upper left corner of every image I display on my page, containing the author's name, and the date it was uploaded.  Here's a crude example:

[cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIZOU.jpg)

I need to add this text using SVG, and I cannot modify the parent svg tag.  Right now, I'm doing this as follows:

```
<g class="mytext" transform="translate(0, 20)">
  <text class="author">
    <tspan class="header" x="0">AUTHOR</tspan>
    <tspan class="content" x="0" dy="2em">Me</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
<g class="mytext" transform="translate(170, 20)">
  <text class="date">
    <tspan class="header" x="0">DATE</tspan>
    <tspan class="content" x="0" dy="2em">December 21, 2015</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnvaro38/)

However, this approach has some problems:

1. I'm not really sure what to do about the author name's length.  A very long name could easily run into the date entry: what is the best practice for dealing with this (I mean this in as much a "design" way as a "programmatic" way).
2. There is a "view larger image" button on the page, which sets a big width and height for the image.  How can I get my text to automatically resize, so that it is the same (relative) size; that is, covers the exact same percentage of the image?

I'm ideally looking for a way to do this with as little meddling on my part as possible (so have the browser/SVG take care of the scaling / text cutoff).  However, there is the problem I mentioned above, that I cannot modify the parent svg tag (so I cannot use viewBox or similar).

Is there a way to solve both problems, without having JS code that hooks into every image resize and dynamically sets a font size?